# Error 1327. Invalid Drive Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, libreoffice

I'm trying to reinstall LibreOffice but getting the titular error.  I think it's because I recombined a partitioned drive (D:\ and E:\ became D:) and LibreOffice was installed on the E:\ drive.  So now I can't re/uninstall it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/327763

Is there anything I can do about this? I'm guessing one fix would be to change all references to the E drive to the D drive, but this isn't really feasible by hand and I don't have the scripting skills to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a registry search and replace tool to solve this.  There's many available online.

There were some OemPath keys I couldn't modify.

Answer (score 1):

If your `E:` drives files/folders is still there, you can do something like this:

Run `subst E: D:\E_Drive` or `subst E: D:\` from a command prompt and that will substitute `E: with D:` and let LibreOffice think that E: is still there. To delete `E:` run `subst E: /D` from a command prompt.

Comment: The E:\ doesn't exist anymore but the references are still to it in the registry.   Would what you suggest still work?  I'm a noob at windows, I mostly use linux.

Comment: I'm trying some software to search and replace, I backed up my keys so we'll see how it goes.